# Hive add file/jar says does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

So I wanted to try custom mapper reducer queries using Hive MAP and REDUCE.

I have written and exported the custom mapper and reducer to jar file and tried adding it from Hive CLI. I am getting does "not exist" error no matter where I am copying the jar. I tried the following.

I copied the file to /usr/local/hive/lib/ , /usr/local/hive/conf/ and /tmp/ then in hdfs also I copied it to / , /user/hive/ and /user/hive/warehouse/

I tried giving the full path then I am getting URL syntax exception

```
hive> add jar 'hdfs://srimanthpc:9000/SpaceTravel.jar';
Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 'hdfs://srimanthpc:9000/SpaceTravel.jar'
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 'hdfs://srimanthpc:9000/SpaceTravel.jar'

hive> add jar 'file:///home/anil/Desktop/SpaceTravel.jar';
Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 'file:///home/anil/Desktop/SpaceTravel.jar'
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 'file:///home/anil/Desktop/SpaceTravel.jar'
```

If I give the path without any schema it says it does not exist. I tried **add file** instead of **add jar** also.

My hive-site.xml has **hive.aux.jars.path** set to /usr/local/hive/lib/. I tried changing this to file:/// hdfs://localhost:9000/ but no change :(

All the online documentation says *ADD JAR|FILE  filepath*. but nobody is mentioning what the that path. :(

I have been stuck here since past 4 hours please help me. What am I missing?

Additional info :
My .bashrc

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove `'` from your query

```
hive> add jar hdfs://srimanthpc:9000/SpaceTravel.jar;
```

in case, master is on localhost

```
hive> add jar hdfs://localhost:9000/SpaceTravel.jar;
```

make sure `SpaceTravel.jar` should be in hdfs.

by using command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```